# Setting up CNAME and MX DNS records DigitalOcean

Tags: dns

I am transfering my domain from network solutions to digitalocean, but want to keep my email server on network solutions. I pointed my DNS server to digitaloceans nameservers, but now I am confused on how to create the MX and CNAME records..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new zone file for your domain in the DigitalOcean DNS control panel. In the zone file you can add MX and CNAME records pointing to your old network solutions server for emails.